# How to isolate PHP across Wordpress Installs

Tags: php, docker, wordpress

TL;DR: How do you isolate php-fpm for different websites running on the same web host?

I'm hosting a Dockerized deployment of Wordpress and it's going well enough that I want to host a few more Wordpress installs. The problem is that I don't like the idea of all sites sharing the same running instance of PHP on the same web root. I'm trying to avoid one bad plugin compromising all websites hosted on the machine.

The deployment looks something like this:

- Docker Compose

  - nginx (virtual servers, read only mounts of web roots)
  - mariadb
  - php-fpm (full read/write of web root)

My current plan is to just start up independent php-fpm instances per Wordpress install and have them mount a sub-directory of the web root. That'll work but it brought up the question of how do traditional sysadmins who don't need to trust their clients deal with multiple virtual hosts?